# Fractal antenna shapes that work for you?

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory, diy

I [just answered this question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/20064/16674), and **I wanted to know if any particular shape has been found to be successful for anyone.**

There [seems to be a lot of research on IEEE](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?queryText=fractal%20antenna&highlight=true&returnType=SEARCH&matchPubs=true&refinements=ContentType:Conferences&refinements=ContentType:Journals&refinements=ContentType:Magazines&returnFacets=ALL&sortType=paper-citations) that indicates that there should be specific fractals that are better than others for any particular application.  Which ones have you found that work well for amateur radio applications?

I prefer PCB-printed copper to formed-wire, but anything, really, is fine.

Comment: By the way, if you're an EE, [I posted a bounty on this question of applications for Fractals in Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/589622/is-there-a-practical-use-for-the-fibonacci-sequence-or-similar-fractal-sequence), if you want to compete for 200 points over there...

Comment: "work" is a bit of an ambiguous term. For what, exactly? Because: most fractal things I've seen are very specific solutions to very specific problems and might or might not be considered "good antennas" in a more general context...

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Well, I mean antennas that work well for Amateur Radio, but in any of the other experiences which people here might find themselves in (that they can talk about), like working w/ police/military/school/etc. That's why I was so general. I just read a paper that explained "chaff" -- very light fractal designs dropped in the sky, that float and flutter... and block radar. Pretty cool! Found the info on chaff in [a rather long PDF entitled "Fractal Antenna Applications" (visual clutter alert).](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221908076_Fractal_Antenna_Applications)

Comment: @MarcusMüller - It seems like some Fractal shapes work better generally, and others seem more specific. (Clutter alter for the web site, not the PDF.) I like stories, and I would like to hear any success stories having to do with diy Fractal antennas.

Comment: hm, not quite sure what you aim for "well for Amateur Radio": What does that entail? Because if you want an antenna that works well in the 2m band, for example, not using a fractal antenna is wiser than using a fractal antenna. If you want to have a multi-band antenna with a suppression for specific directions and / or bands, things that are hard to design for with classical antenna shapes, then you might have a use case where a fractal antenna might be an interesting approach

Comment: Fractal antennas also work well at trapping dryer lint, snow and ice, they're good for impressing your ham friends around the bbq, and if the fractal is carried all the way to the feedpoint, great solder wicking ability for a strong joint.

Comment: There are a couple of classic antennas that are actually (degenerate) fractal and work very well: several spirals, and of course, the log periodic antenna.  Somehow those get left out when discussing fractal antennas.

Comment: This question seems overly-broad to me, because there are infinitely many possible fractal antennas, and because the question doesn't define the criteria for such an antenna to be considered to "work".  In other words, it's open-ended and vague; how should a good answer be distinguished from a bad one?  The OP might be interested in collecting stories of successful antennas, but this site, and every other Stack Exchange site, is about creating a database of high-quality answers to objectively-answerable questions.

Comment: @rclocher3 I agree. Also: what this question might attract is different opinions.

Comment: This question also lacks important details: what is the desired frequency or band?

Comment: Antenna models don't need frequency or band until you go to build them.  Many antenna designs express all dimensions in wavelength, so frequency is totally irrelevant to the model.

Comment: @user10489 Fair enough. I was just thinking that the question might not fit the StackExchange model.

Comment: @user10489 but that doesn't really work with fractal designs – they need to be designed such that the self-repeating patterns, which can't self-repeat down below the atomic size level, become technically feasible. Also note your question is **explicitly** about practically useful antennas, not about theoretical antenna designs. So, please don't self-contradict yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: question changed since I wrote this answer.

Two classic and highly effective fractal antennas are the log periodic antenna and the many variations (planar, conical, cylindrical, etc.) of the log spiral antenna.  The main characteristic of both of these antenna families is extremely broad bandwidth, which can be attributed to the fractal self similarity at multiple scales.

Most other fractal antennas are either less well known or are less effective than an isotropic antenna or the fat wire equivalent antenna, or are extremely specialized.  (If anyone knows of others, they should add another answer here!)

Around 2000, when idea of the fractal antenna was  first published, there was a lot of enthusiasm, but most papers didn't include any studies of the effectiveness of such antennas.  In the following years, a number of additional papers were published, finding that all the new fractal antennas they actually characterized either had lower gain or lower efficiency (or both) than similar antennas that just used fat wires instead of fractal geometry.  Fractal antennas did inspire some innovations in antenna theory around the nature of what increases the bandwidth of an antenna.

In a brief search of the literature, I see a lot of fractal antennas, but the papers I found either did not mention antenna effectiveness at all, or admit poor performance.  I have heard of rumors of proprietary or trade secret fractal antennas in commercial use, but until something is published about them, they are just rumors.  There are two that work, so it is possible there are others.

Comment: A log periodic is a [**fractal antenna**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_antenna)? It's just a series of tapered elements on a boom, and doesn't have a fractal pattern that I am aware of.

Comment: [Fractal antenna patent and description](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6452553)

Comment: @MikeWaters - The log periodic antenna was invented before Fractal Mathematics was discovered as an entirely new branch of mathematics.  Nevertheless, the log periodic antenna **is** Fractal because it is self-similar at multiple magnifications (zoom-levels). By this definition, some simple curves are fractal, as is the Fibonacci series, and everything based off of it, contrary to popular internet belief.

Comment: I've always thought of Fractal (antennas) as being *scale independent* but in *discrete chunks*, so a  Vivaldi, Log spiral, Conical log spiral etc don't really count. Things like the Sierpenski snowflake, which apparently offer performance at multiple bands.

Comment: @tomnexus - I've explored different Fractal Universes with the excellent XaoS Real-Time Fractal Zoomer, and some universes are all broken and discrete, while other universes are smooth, and many have smooth vs. broken (fractured?) areas.  Self-similarity is required (though similarity may be distorted at deeper zoom levels). Smoothness / brokenness / discreteness is not necessarily required, or contraindicative.

Comment: The log periodic is a degenerate fractal antenna, as in, it doesn't have higher fractal dimension, but it is still a fractal antenna.

Comment: I've added some text reflecting history of the fractal antenna.  Patents are a poor source of information here, as while a patent must work, it doesn't have to tell you why or if it is effective.

Comment: @user10489 but then the yagi-uda is a degenerate fractal antenna too. and, by only relatively slight extension, the dipole just as well.

Comment: No.  The yagi-uda antenna is not self-similar at multiple scales, and is not broad band.   A log perodic has every element driven.  The yagi has one driven element and no others, so it can't be self similar.  Note that the link in the second comment calls the log periodic as "first order fractal".

Comment: Also, that link also lumps in the biconical antenna (not the dipole) as first order fractal.  Note that a conical antenna is also very broad band, where the dipole is not.